# jquery effects not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you go to [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/artistSubscription/list) and click on the unsubscribe link the corresponding table row is immediately deleted. However the code executed is:

```
SF.delete = function(selector) {
    $(selector).slideUp('slow').remove();
};
```

So you should see the element slowly slide up, rather than just immediately disappearing. Why is this effect not working? I'm seeing the same behavior in both firefox and chrome.

### Update

I've implemented [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)' suggestion at the URL above. However, the image "jumps" sidewards as the row slides up. I'm guessing this is caused by the insertion of the `<div>`, is there any way to make it a bit smoother?

Comment: Actually it was misspelled before - I'm British myself so I'm slightly embarrassed about my Americanised correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Table rows will always be tall enough to hold their contents](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/animating-table-rows-with-jquery.html), so when jQuery reduces the row's height, nothing happens.

Instead, [you can write](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/LjHBR/)

```
$('tr')
    .children('td, th')
    .animate({ padding: 0 })
    .wrapInner('<div />')
    .children()
    .slideUp(function() { $(this).closest('tr').remove(); });
```

Comment: Thanks, in particular for the jsFiddle example

Comment: I realise I'm pushing my luck here, but if you have the inclination/curiousity/time, would you mind having a look at my update above?

Comment: You probably have horizontal padding that the animation is removing.  Change it to animate paddingTop and bottom only instead.

Comment: Do you mean replace `.animate({ padding: 0 })` with `.animate({ paddingTop: 0 }).animate({ paddingBottom: 0 })` ?

Comment: `paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try replacing `.animate({ padding: 0 })` with `.animate({ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 })` I'll accept this answer if it works out

Comment: No, there's still an unpleasant wobbling of the image in the row below that which is deleted

Comment: It works for me.  `SF.deleteRow = function(selector) {
    $(selector)
        .children('td, th')
        .animate({ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 })
        .wrapInner('<div />')
        .children()
        .slideUp(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

};`

Comment: I've updated the website with the code you've proposed. If you delete the Madonna row it seems to work OK, but then when you delete the Radiohead row there's a very noticeable jumping effect as the U2 row is slid into position.

Comment: I guess we're straying from the original topical, so I'll post this problem with the effect as a separate question